# How to detect if user is switched (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm using SwitchUserFilter (Spring 3.1) to temporary work as another user. The filter provides the URL for exiting from switched state, but I can't find the clean way to provide such a URL on the web page. For example there are lots of useful tags in Grail such as `<sec:ifSwitched>`, `<sec:switchedUserOriginalUsername/>`, `</sec:ifSwitched>`. Is there anything similar for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution. Not that elegant as Grails tags, though.

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR')">
        <a href='<c:url value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />'>
            Resume as Admin</a>
</sec:authorize>
```